# Understanding how Git LFS repository works for developers who don't have LFS extension installed

Tags: git, large-files, git-lfs, large-file-support

As the title already says, I am interested in how would a git repository with LFS files behave for developers who don't have LFS git extension installed (cloning of affected files, committing of affected files, etc). Would it be even possible for them to clone such repository (or at least by LFS affected files)?

[This article](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/advanced-topics/git-lfs) explains LFS for git in a very nice way (for beginners).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical spec is actually pretty understandable too :
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md

`git lfs` replaces the actual files with a text pointer tracked in the git repository :

> Example of a v1 text pointer:
>
> ```
> version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
> oid sha256:4d7a214614ab2935c943f9e0ff69d22eadbb8f32b1258daaa5e2ca24d17e2393
> size 12345
> (ending \n)
> ```

Someone without the lfs extension would see these files instead of the expected content, but would otherwise be able to interact with the repository.

Comment: So that means they will get only the pointer file but not the actual file referenced by the pointer?

Comment: @emir : yes, that's what they will see